# Log ssh communications

Tags: ssh, command

I have a closed source program which calls server over SSH and executes a set of commands.

Could you tell me how can I log all commands?

My server is under Ubuntu.

Comment: maybe this can help you http://serverfault.com/questions/559658/log-commands-executed-over-ssh/559683#559683

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/470755/log-all-commands-run-by-admins-on-production-servers/475134#475134
a more detailed answer explaining how to use `auditd`

Answer (score 2):

[Snoopy](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/88) can be used to log all commands ran on a system. Logs will be sent to syslog.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly *how* it's doing it's thing, there's no one answer that I can give.  However, a few possibilities:

- *It uses keys for authentication, and runs a command it passes at login*: This is easy.  Add a `command=` to the entry in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` that calls a script that logs the command it runs, and then just execs the command.  Transparent, simple.
- *It uses keys for authentication, runs a shell, and stuffs commands down the shell*: Harder, but still straightforward.  Again, `command=` in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to run a shell of your choosing, which could be something like [sudoshell](http://www.egbok.com/sudoscript/sudoshell.1.html) or something else that logs all commands (for super bonus trickery, you could even use `script` for full replayability).
- *It uses passwords*: No `command=` trickery allowed here, you're going to have to go the whole hog and use something like [snoopy](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/snoopy) to log everything that happens -- but unless this program is the only thing using SSH, you'll likely end up with a lot of logs.

Comment: the program can use key based auth. do you have script sample to log calls? thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the close source program allows you to edit remote SSH parameters or you can put the commands into a shell script, you can wrap your execution around the "script" command on the remote server like this:

`ssh 192.168.15.200 'script ps.log -c "ps -ef"'`

In this case, the output of `ps -ef` is saved into the file ps.log