# Logging remote commands sent during SSH session, so the log would be unencrypted

Tags: ssh, logging, encryption, putty

I connect to server A (running OpenSSH server in Linux OS) using Putty:

```
localhost% putty.exe A
```

How to cause the SSH server to log the commands sent from localhost in unencrypted manner.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I got the question right: You want to log all commands issued in a SSH session?

I'd suggest using `auditd` for that. Don't forget that once a user becomes `root`, local logs will not do you any good and can be forged. So combining this with a syslog server might be a good idea, depending on your requirements.

See these links:

[Documentation for auditd](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-security_sd_draft/cha.audit.comp.html)

Make `auditd` record commands issued as `root` with the userid `sudo` or `su` was run as:

[Getting auditd to record the original user](https://serverfault.com/questions/473601/getting-auditd-to-record-the-original-user/475670#475670)