# auditd auid changes after su

Tags: pam, selinux, auditd

I try to implement individual accountability for my RHEL systems using selinux and the audit.log. I followed the instructions given here: [Log all commands run by admins on production servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/470755/log-all-commands-run-by-admins-on-production-servers/475134#475134)

If I understand it correctly, the pam_loginuid.so should keep the UID which was used to login and set it as the AUID in the audit.log file. Unfortunately that does not work after *su*. When I login to the system and call *cat /proc/self/loginuid* it displays my correct UID. If I invoke *sudo su -* and call *cat /proc/self/loginuid* again, it displays 0. Also the ID 0 is used in the audit.log as AUID for commands I invoke after *sudo su -*.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my pam.d/sshd file:

```
auth       include      system-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so revoke
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    include      system-auth
```

I enabled audit=1 in /etc/grub.conf and edited /etc/audit/audit.rules as described in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not load `pam_loginuid.so` module from any of the following `/etc/pam.d/` files:

- `su`
- `sudo`
- files included in the files `su` and `sudo`, via `@include`

Edit:
See also this bug https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=741546