# How to log administrator activities in Red Hat Enterprise?

Tags: redhat, logging, root

Is it better to use auditd or sudo logs to log root and other user activities on a Red hat enterprise machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Auditd](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/chap-system_auditing.html) and a remote syslog server, as a root user could potentially alter any local logs.

Some more details can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/470755/log-all-commands-run-by-admins-on-production-servers).

Comment: Note that auditd can slow down a system significantly.