# Log root SSH commands on OpenVZ Node

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, logging, log-files

Is there a way to log root commands from SSH on OpenVZ Node?
I tried Snoopy and I was not able to exclude everything and leave only SSH commands.

@edit
I want log ONLY commands sent through SSH/SFTP from remote host, because on my openvz node root is used to run many other commands locally. For example Snoopy is logging everything that happens on system (that is a lot of trash..), but I want to see what is done by any person on root by SSH/SFTP.

Comment: Yes, look up how-to docs on using `auditd` and creating audit.rules.

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron says, you need **auditd**. Your question is not a duplicate of this other one I found, but the accepted answer is perfect for you:

[Log all commands run by admins on production servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/470755/log-all-commands-run-by-admins-on-production-servers)

And I just found this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/422243/how-to-audit-tty-for-a-specified-user-in-ssh-connection

It demonstrates that you need to use PAM to target SSH in the way you want by adding something along the lines of this to your configuration.

*/etc/pam.d/sshd*

```
session required pam_tty_audit.so enable=*
```

Comment: Why isn't it a duplicate? It looks like exactly the same question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because he's having an issue with filtering based on SSH "Log root SSH commands"... I guess you could say it's a duplicate, I see it as more specific. I have some more specific info to provide, updating my answer now.

Comment: And I expect he said ssh because of inexperience, not because he wanted to limit the auditing.

Comment: @MichaelHampton He said he couldn't exclude non-ssh stuff from snoopy logging.

Comment: Nope. I want log ONLY commands sent through SSH/SFTP from remote host, because on my openvz node root is used to run many other commands locally. For example Snoopy is logging everything that happens on system (that is a lot of trash..), but I want to see what is done by any person on root by SSH/SFTP.

Comment: @MichaelHampton can you remove "duplicate"?