# How to log commands executed by users with non-interactive shells

Tags: linux, logging, shell

I want to log commands executed by an application server(resin) to catch things like "cat /etc/passwd" or "whoami" being executed by user resin.

However, since the user resin uses a /bin/false shell, I can't just edit bashrc file as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93566/how-to-log-all-bash-commands-by-all-users-on-a-server)

So what are my options to do that?

Comment: The solution is auditd - [replace `euid=0`](https://serverfault.com/a/475134/37681)  with the UID number for your resin user and you're done.