# Monitoring users logged in with SSH-CA (certificates)

Tags: ssh, logging, root, audit

I was hoping to get some help with an approach that could be used...

I am building out a solution that will use SSH-CA (that is, SSH where authentication is done via certificates).

Flow is simple:

**1) User generates key pair**

**2) Authenticates with HSM and gets public key signed**

**3) SSH server validates signature and cert and allows access**

(there are extra bits, but this is basically it).

Here's my problem, I can monitor the cert requests and the SSH interactions, but how do I monitor the actions of a user?

As this is for devOps staff, they need root, so mostly folks will all be logged in to the SSH session as root.

I still need to tie commands issued to actual staff names or IDs.

Any smart ideas?

I thought of using:

- Exploiting `LD_PRELOAD` to provide a rudimentary bread-crumb trail.
- Usage of multiple certificate authorities, one per user.
- Usage of UNIX groups, employing groups of groups.

But they're all icky solutions.

Comment: Use `auditd` for this. See https://serverfault.com/questions/470755/log-all-commands-run-by-admins-on-production-servers/475134#475134

Comment: thanks @fuero, wouldn't think require additional CA per user? Also one last item, would this cover context switch, i.e. user login as X but then SU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make this an answer :-)

For auditing commands issued by users (even after they switch to other uids with `su` or `sudo`) you need `auditd`.

You may find details on how to set it up, how to interpret the logs and caveats [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/470755/log-all-commands-run-by-admins-on-production-servers/475134#475134).