# How to enable sudo and disbale sudo su on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: permissions, configuration, user-permissions

We need to capture user commands, on logs now the user has Sudo access. we have planned to disable sudo and they need to use sudo before the command. How to enable sudo and disable sudo su on ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This is useless, they can just do `sudo -i` to enter a root shell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log all commands run by admins on production servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/470755/log-all-commands-run-by-admins-on-production-servers)

Comment: Hi Sir, I am not clear on your comment. anything we need to be configure?.