# Which history file does the command in ssh client commandline go to?

Tags: ssh, history

If I do `ssh user@server` and then, inside the bash session, I run whatever, when ssh session is closed these executed commands go to .bash_history file. Simple and clear.

But if I do `ssh user@server command`, this command isn't logged anywhere. Beyond the reason (I suspect no bash session is spawned), what I want to know is: how can I log what commands have been executed in this manner, then?

Comment: Do you want to save history on the remote server?

Comment: `ssh user@server command` runs your remote shell (whatever that is: might be bash, might be something else) to execute the command, but it runs this shell as _noninteractive_. bash maintains and stores command history only when run as _interactive_. Maybe interactive is what you consider a 'session'. _If_ you use (client) publickey and not (ever) password to authenticate, you can [set `command=` in (the relevant line(s) of) the `authorized_keys` file](https://serverfault.com/questions/559658/log-commands-executed-over-ssh)

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks a lot for your clear explanation. So I infer from your words that if I don't use command= option in authorized_keys (nor the ForceCommand option in sshd_config), there's no way to know which (arbitrary) command a ssh client could have executed in every noninteractive session. Mmmm...I don't know if this is something to worry about...thanks anyway